# Avoid vertical spaces before figure to fill the page

Tags: spacing, floats, vertical

I'm writing a latex document which contains a table. This table is doesn't fit the actual page so it's placed in the next page.

The problem is that vertical spaces are added automatically in the previous page in order to fill the page and I want to avoid that from happening.

I use H in order to add the table figure.

[image: My problem]

Comment: `[H]` is almost a guarantee for bad layout. Try with `[htbp]` instead.

Comment: @samcarter htbp is changing position of the table.

Comment: Yes, `[htbp]` will select a position for the table which results in a good layout without such large gaps between the paragraphs

Comment: In addition to `[htbp]`, at least two more things can affect this.  What document class?  `memoir` has `\sloppybottom` and I think most have `\raggedbottom`.  Also, `\parskip` will affect this.  I had a similar issue and use `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 18pt minus 2pt}` in preamble (but you will need to decide what values work for you, if you use it).

Comment: @AwesomeGuy If the tables move you should cross-references ( \ref  - \label) and make autoexplicative captions, or alternatively do not use floats. Then the table will never move and will be in the  exact lecture point that you want, but the layout will be a pain. Use [H] is the same except that you can add  captions (now useless).  Choose: good layouts or fixed positions. You cannot have  both  without a careful redesign the document.

Comment: @AwesomeGuy  without a [MWNCCE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (minimal working non censored code example)  is a guess game propose you how reduce that vertical glues, but even if you are able to do that, then you will have a huge final space. Except for final pages, I am not sure of what is worse.

Comment: producing the big space is exactly what `[H]` is designed to do, it opts for ugly space rather than allowing the figure to float to avoid a bad page break.

Comment: @whatisit what you say is all good except the parskip value is very dangerous it allows values to go as low as -2pt ie letting paragraphs over-print each other if the page is very full.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle while I don't disagree with you, I was having issues without allowing a negative value in a particularly long document with many tables and figures - many very close to each other.  It should definitely be used with caution, as you say!

Comment: @whatisit OK but you should warn people that it will cause over-printing, not just suggest it as a value with no comment:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason LaTeX has floating environments such as `figure` and `table` is to avoid large white space gaps at page breaks by moving the figure to a position which produces a better page break.

By using `[H]` you disable the float mechanism so you get the bad page break that latex would have avoided by floating the figure.

Depending on the use case and reasons why you used `[H]` you need to accept the space, or move the figure in the source file, rearranging the text so there is more text on the page, or use the float mechanism `[htbp]`.

If you decide to accept the space, you may prefer `\raggedbottom` so all the excess space comes at the bottom of the page.